Mirror modifier works incorrectly on a simple rotated object? At wits' end
I was reviewing a student's assignment and they had this simple object that behaves incorrectly when mirror is applied. Thing is, I don't get what's wrong. All transforms are applied/zeroed out, the axis is correct. Nothing is affecting. What am I missing here? Why is the cylinder being mirrored at an angle instead of horizontally like expected?
My only hunch is that the object was somehow applied rotation while in another rotation mode (Quaternion) and then applied again in another mode? not sure if that makes sense...

Blend file

You have a rotation in the Delta Transform panel, bring it back to 0:


Hmm you're right, HOWEVER, why was rotation at 0,0,0 then?

You're right, I've edited my answer

Thanks - wasn't even aware that was a thing
